# ExtJS Store load listener not being invoked

Tags: extjs

I have a custom data store which stores the information whether the store has been loaded once or not.

```
/**
 * Custom DataStore which stores the information whether data has been loaded once or not.
 */
Ext.example.Store = Ext.extend(Ext.data.Store, {
    loaded: false,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.superclass().initComponent.call(this);
        this.addEvents('load','beforeload');
    },
    isLoaded : function() {
        return this.loaded;
    },
    listeners: {
        'load' :  function(store,records,options) {
            this.loaded = true;
        }
    }
});
```

This was working fine until recently I added a 'beforeload' event listener to an instance of this store. The 'load' listener does not get invoked now.

```
var accountsDataStore = new Ext.example.Store({

    id : 'account',
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url : 'app/account/fetch/all',
        method : 'post',
        api : {
            destroy : 'app/account/delete'
        }
    }),
    reader : accountReader,
    writer : accountWriter,
    remoteSort : true,
    sortInfo : {
        field : 'createdOn',
        direction : "DESC"
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, options) {
            var sort = options.params.sort;
            // setting the sort parameters to match the property names in the DTO
            switch(sort) {
                case 'company' :
                    options.params.sort = 'company.name';
                    break;
                default:
                    // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

});
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Also please let me know your suggestions to improve

Comment: Where are you loading the store? I can't see any autoLoad : true or accountsDataStore.load() option.

Comment: I try to load the store on a tab click. My intent is not to load the store if the store has been previously loaded-                       `if(!accountsDataStore.isLoaded()) {
   accountsDataStore.load();
}`. The `isLoaded` always return false, since the load listener is never invoked.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem. Can you please tell how did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you should never set objects on the prototype, unless you really know what it means (that it will be shared by all instances and can be overridden on a per instance basis)

In Ext JS, I only set config options on the prototype that are only for convenience and may be overridden by the caller.

Your first class `Ext.example.Store` puts listeners on its prototype.
Then you go and overwrite it in accountsDataStore by passing in a listeners object into the config.

To fix your problem, instead of setting listeners on the prototype, just call `this.on('event')` from the constructor.

```
/**
 * Custom DataStore which stores the information whether data has been loaded once or not.
 */

Ext.example.Store = Ext.extend(Ext.data.Store, {
    loaded: false,
    constructor: function() {
        this.superclass().constructor.call(this);
        // No need to call this, you're not adding any events
        // this.addEvents('load','beforeload');
        this.on('load', function(store,records,options) {
            this.loaded = true;
        }, this);
    },
    isLoaded : function() {
        return this.loaded;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the "beforeload" event states:

> "Fires before a request is made for a new data object. If the
>   beforeload handler returns false the load action will be canceled."

You could trying returning true from your beforeload listener to ensure the load action still runs.

Answer (score 1):

store.totalCount

if loaded, this property return a number
else
this property is undefined
(extjs-4.1.0-rc1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think there is a problem with scope. Please try it this way:

```
listeners: {
        'load' :  {
            fn : function(store,records,options) {
                 console.log(this, this.loaded);
                 this.loaded = true;
            },
            scope : this
        }
    }
```

Or you can use:

```
listeners: {
        'load' :  function(store,records,options) {
            store.loaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The fact is the load listener is not even getting invoked.

Comment: change this line: this.superclass().initComponent.call(this); to Ext.example.Store.superclass.initComponent.call(this);  And do not add a load event as a store load event already exists.

Comment: unfortunately it seems thats not the issue

Comment: when I take off the beforeload listener, the control enters the load listener.